# Golang mock forces to change functions definition

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing

I have the following function:

```
func getPrice(date string) {
  url := (fmt.Printf("http://endponint/%s", date))
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    // Unmarshall body and get price
    return price
}
```

In order to unit test this function I'm forced to refactor to:

```
func getPrice(client HTTPClient, date string) {
  url := (fmt.Printf("http://endponint/%s", date))
    resp, err := client.Get(url)
    // Unmarshall body and get price
    return price
}
```

And my test looks like this:

```
type MockClient struct {
    Response *http.Response
    Err      error
}

func (m *MockClient) Get(url string) (*http.Response, error) {
    return m.Response, m.Err
}

mockResp := &http.Response{
    StatusCode: http.StatusOK,
    Body:       ioutil.NopCloser(strings.NewReader("mock response")),
}

client := &MockClient{
    Response: mockResp,
    Err:      nil,
}

data, err := getData(client, "http://example.com")
```

Is this only way to test in Go, is there no way to mock an API which is not injected into function?

Comment: Are you trying to mock the http.Get call? If so, you have to change `getData`, because as it is written, it is using the global `http.Client` instance. You cannot generalize this to unit testing APIs in Go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiomatic way to do HTTP testing with Go is using [http/httptest](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httptest) ([examples](https://go.dev/src/net/http/httptest/example_test.go))

In your case, all you would need to do is make the base URL injectable:

```golang
var APIEndpoint = "http://endpoint/"

func getPrice(date string) (int, error) {
  url := (fmt.Printf("%s/%s", APIEndpoint, date))
  resp, err := http.Get(url)
  // Unmarshall body and get price
  return price, nil
}
```

And then in each test:

```golang
srv := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Write the expected response to the writer
}))
defer srv.Close()
APIEndpoint = srv.URL
price, err := getPrice("1/1/2023")
// Handle error, check return
```

A slightly better design would be to wrap your API in a client `struct` and make `getPrice` a receiver method:

```golang
type PriceClient struct {
    Endpoint string
}

func (pc *PriceClient) GetPrice(date string) (int, error) {
  url := (fmt.Printf("%s/%s", pc.Endpoint, date))
  resp, err := http.Get(url)
  // Unmarshall body and get price
  return price, nil
}
```

```golang
srv := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Write the expected response to the writer
}))
defer srv.Close()
c := &PriceClient{Endpoint: srv.URL}
price, err := c.GetPrice("1/1/2023")
// Handle error, check return
```

For future reference, you should also have a look at [gomock](https://github.com/golang/mock), since most other mocking problems you'll encounter do not have solutions built-in to the language.

Answer (score 1):

you can mock `getPrice` like so:

in your package define a variable `getPrice` and set it to your function.

```
package server

var getPrice = getPriceFn

func getPriceFn(date string) {
  url := (fmt.Printf("http://endponint/%s", date))
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    // Unmarshall body and get price
    return price
}
```

in your test file give the `getPrice` variable a mock function.

```
package server

func mockGetPrice(date string) (int, error) {
    return 1,nil
}

func testSomething(t *testing.T) {
    getPrice = mockGetPrice
    // do stuff
}
```

if you want to mock `http.get` so you can test getPrice, then you can use the `httpmock` package.

```
import "github.com/jarcoal/httpmock"

func TestGetPrice(date string) {
  httpmock.Activate()
  defer httpmock.DeactivateAndReset()
  url := (fmt.Printf("http://endponint/%s", date))
  httpmock.RegisterResponder("GET", url,
    httpmock.NewStringResponder(200, "foo"))
  getPrice(date)
  // make assertions
}
```

Comment: You got my question wrong! I want to mock http.Get inorder to test `getPrice` function. Nice trick through!

Comment: i updated the answer with an example of mocking http.Get

Comment: I ended up using `httptest.NewServer`, thanks @skeeter